# Active Directory authentication from Java

Tags: java, authentication, web, active-directory, frontend

Hello all :) I want to authenticate an user from the Frontend Application with AD.

The flow would be:

FE (Angular) -> BE (Java) -> AD

What is the most secure way to implement this authentication?
At the moment the password is sent in plain text from FE to BE, and BE is using JNDI and LDAP to verify against AD.

Comment: Is the front-end external or internal?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.